# c# Triple DES encryption with two keys

Tags: c#, encryption, key, tripledes

I have to encrypt a hex string with two keys. My code for this looks like that:

```
public byte[] TripleDes(byte[] inputBuffer, byte[] key)
{
    byte[] result;

    using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
       des.Key = key;
       // des.KeySize = 128;   <- wrong, overrides the values of the key
       des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
       des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

       cryptoStream.Write(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
       cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
       result = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return result;
}
```

The key which is set is 16 bytes and consist of two parts: first part = key to encrypt, second part = key to decrypt. The inputBuffer is 8 bytes. When I do the encryption like that, my result is 16 bytes instead of 8 bytes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: what code you need? that's my full code for the Triple DES enryption method.

Comment: Try saving inputbuffer.length into an int and give that variable as third argument in cryptostream.write.

Comment: for example the inputBuffer is in hex "4E6F772069732074" and the key is in hex "0123456789ABCDEF23456789ABCDEF01" the result is 16 bytes "7def96537bbd8e6f15e100ba4ff7e1bb"

Comment: doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Just my guess, but can't you half the key and then check the bytes?

Comment: so then i have just the encryption key set? then an exception occurs when I set the key "Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.". and which bytes should I check?

Comment: I found a mistake. when I set the key with "des.Key = key;" then the next line "des.KeySize = 128;" overrides it's values. So I deleted this line. Now the values of the key and the buffer are correct but my problem with a too large result still exists :(

Comment: What do you want this method to return in the first place?

Comment: the inputBuffer encrypted with Triple DES (and the given key(s))

Comment: Try to replace stream.ToArray(); with cryptoStream.ToArray();

Comment: cryptoStream has not "ToArray"-method so I have to use the "stream.ToArray()" method. When I call "cryptoStream.Flush()" instead of "cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()" the result is 8 bytes (but not the expected encrypted inputBuffer)

Comment: I'm just debugging with you, try cryptoStream.CopyTo(stream, inputBuffer.Length()) before result = stream.ToArray()

Comment: the stream is in write mode then this method is not available. I search for the difference between "Flush()" und "FlushFinalBlock()". I write when I found out sth new. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was correct but the order not. The configuration of the "TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider" instance happened after the "CreateEncryptor()" method was instanziated. So the correct code is:

```
public byte[] TripleDes(byte[] inputBuffer, byte[] key)
{
    using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        des.Key = key;
        des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        byte[] result;

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
            cryptoStream.Flush();
            //cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            result = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The "Flush()" and the "FlushFinalBlock()" method return both the same result, except the "FlushFinalBlock" has 8 bytes additional data which I don't need and I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

check `stream.Length`.
Use this function to change stream to byte array

```
 public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
        {
            if (input is MemoryStream)
            {
                return ((MemoryStream)input).ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                return ReadFully(input);
            }
        }
```

Comment: the stream.Length is 16 bytes for some reason. With your method I get the same result. In my opinion your method does nothing different (in my case) than stream.ToArray() except if it isn't a MemoryStream it results in an exception..?